# How do I find the input parameters of an instantiated Python class object?

Tags: python, class, oop

My goal is to reload the class object using `__init__(...)` but with an extra argument. So I am trying to get the original class object input parameters to perform this reloading. However, some input arguments of the original class object is not saved as an attribute: example: `self.a = a`. How do I perform such reloading by finding the input parameters that is not saved?

Example code:

```
class TestOnly:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
        self.a = a
        self.c = c


test = TestOnly(1, 2)

# I want to know b=2 here:
test = test.__init__(a=test.a, b=something_i_want_to_know, c=123)
```

How can I find out b=2 programmatically?

Comment: If `b` is never saved into an attribute inside of `__init__` then you cannot recall that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can never access the b variable as you have not stored it in the class.

```
class TestOnly:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
        self.a = a
        self.c = c

test = TestOnly(1, 2)
```

Your new shiny TestOnly object is now stored in the test variable.

You can then call

```
print (test.a) 
print(test.c)
```

As you stored them with `self.a =a` etc

You can't however access b as you didn't save it into the object.
And after **init** has been called the b variable will be discarded.

Don't use

```
Test.__init__()
```

Although it may be possible (I'm not sure) , it's not the way to use it as TestOnly() does this already.